# Is it safe to redefine \@starttoc?

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol, tocloft

I'm using `tocloft` and would like to produce a two-column table of contents. While it's easy to just wrap the whole toc in a `multicol`-environment, I don't like the look of that, because the title gets wrapped into that as well, which makes the second column start above the title.

As `tocloft` redefines `\tableofcontents` using `\AtBeginDocument`, I thought instead of overwriting that definition at a later point I might just redefine `\@starttoc` to produce what I want, like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
% tocloft redefines \tableofcontents \AtBeginDocument
% As I don't want the title to be part of the two column layout,
% it seems easiest to just add the multicols to \@starttoc.
\let\@starttocorg\@starttoc
\def\@starttoc#1{%
    \begin{multicols*}{2}%
        \@starttocorg{#1}%
    \end{multicols*}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

But as I don't know what `\@starttoc` does internally, I'm not sure if it's safe to do that. Are there any implications I don't see? (I suppose I could also re-phrase the question as *Can it really be that easy?*)

Comment: You can look how `\@starttoc` is defined using `\show\@starttoc`. From my point of view, it looks save. Using a KOMA-class you don't need to use `tocloft` and should use `tocbasic`, imho.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for the `tobasic` hint, I'll have a look at that ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the KOMA-Script classes `scrartcl`, `scrreprt` and `scrbook` load and use package `tocbasic` for the ToC and the Lists. `tocbasic` uses `\tocbasic@starttoc` based on `\@starttoc`. `\tocbasic@starttoc` and `\@starttoc` both are internal commands and should not be redefined by users. But `tocbasic` provides two hooks to execute code before (`\BeforeStartingTOC`) and after (`\AfterStartingTOC`) `@starttoc`.

Note that `\BeforeStartingTOC` and `\AfterStartingTOC` are at the same group level (inside the same group), so you can use:

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\end{document}
```

Or with the starred version of `multicols`:

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols*}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols*}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Needs at least two LaTeX runs.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{part}
[...]
```

[image]

Or for the star version of `multicols` (no balanced columns)

```
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2}}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of this (honestly interested, as I don't see any problem with redefining `\@starttoc`)?

Comment: You could also use `\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}`. @Skillmon `\AfterTOCHead` and `\AfterStartingTOC` are official and documented hooks provided by package `tocbasic`. So there is really no need to redefine an internal command.

Comment: I would probably use this. But while this works for `multicols`, when I try to use the starred version `\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\begin{multicols*}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols*}}` I get an error: _!LaTeX Error: \begin{multicols} on input line 680 ended by \end{multicols*}._

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: @esdd: `\AfterStartingTOC` is misleading. It should better be named as `\AtEndTOC`

Comment: While the starred version doesn't produce an error anymore, if the second column isn't filled to the end (in your example, remove everything after section 10.2), the whitespace between all the right-column entries is stretched to fill the column, which looks ugly. This doesn't happen with the `\@starttoc` version ...

Comment: If I use `\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\vfill\endmulticols}` it works again as it should. But why should I need to use that for this version and not for the `\@starttoc` one?

Comment: Use `\raggedcolumns` (see edited answer) then it should behave like the star version

Comment: I can't see why, but using `\raggedcolumns` makes the toc title disappear.