# How can I format the table of contents like that of the tcolorbox manual?

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

The [manual for tcolorbox](https://texdoc.org/serve/tcolorbox.pdf/0) is an immense volume that I have been slowing chipping away at, but it has a rather inspiring table of contents that I would like to reproduce and then modify. How do I code a table of contents like the one that wraps around the table of contents in the tcolorbox manual?

A search for 'table of contents' in the documentation gave only one result on page 122, but it is not clear to me whether it is relevant to my goal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source code for the `tcolorbox` manual is [here,](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) split into different files.  The code for the table of contents is in `tcolorbox.doc.abstract.tex` and says:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,enhanced jigsaw,title={Contents},fonttitle=\bfseries\Large,
  colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,before=\par\bigskip\noindent,
  interior style={fill overzoom image=goldshade.png,fill image opacity=0.25},
  colbacktitle=red!50!yellow!75!black,
  enlargepage flexible=\baselineskip,pad at break*=3mm,
  height fixed for=first and middle,
  watermark color=yellow!75!red!25!white,
  watermark text={\bfseries\Large Contents},
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={enhanced,boxrule=0.5mm,
    frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west) -- (frame.north west)
    -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
    -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
    interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
    -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
    -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
    -- cycle;}  },
  drop fuzzy shadow]
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{toc}
\makeatother
\end{tcolorbox}
```

The `breakable` key here requires you to load `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}` after `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`,  and enables the automatic page breaking.  This code also uses `\tcbuselibrary{skins}`.  The `enhanced jigsaw` key (a shortcut for `skin=enhanced jigsaw`) handles the top and bottom borders, so if you wanted there to be a frame at the bottom of page 3 and the top and bottom of page 4, for example, you could change this to `skin=enhanced`.

The `\@starttoc` command is defined in the LaTeX kernel, used here rather than `\tableofcontents`to skip unwanted formatting such as page breaks and title.  If you wanted to change the appearance of the table of contents inside the box, you would normally [use a package like](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390842/is-it-safe-to-redefine-starttoc) `tocloft` or `tocbasic`.  That link, for example, shows how to format the table of contents in two columns.

Answer (score 3):

Page 167. Change colors and put
\tableofcontents
Into example (instead of \lipsum[2])

[image]