# Two-column table of contents in single-column scrbook

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, two-column, scrbook

I am working with a `scrbook` (KOMA-script's book documentclass) which is, overall, a one-column document. However, as I have `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}`, my table of contents is relatively loose and short, and I would like to have the table of contents in two columns.

My first attempt was to simply see how it works when I pass `twocolumn` to the class and use `\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}` to allow the TOC to be in two columns. (For some reason, it seems that even for two-column documents, KOMA-script does set the TOC in two columns by default, and here we're letting that happen.) The results, at least on the TOC page, are exactly what I want. However, obviously this makes the entire document two columns while I want it to be in one.

Using `\twocolumn\tableofcontents\onecolumn` in place of `\tableofcontents`, while having `\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}` active, yields *almost* the correct result. However, the heading for the TOC, which says "Contents" is slightly shifted up from it's original position. This makes it inconsistent from the rest of the document and is thus a bit ugly. Would it be possible to have the contents of the TOC in two columns, while having the heading thereof typeset exactly as it would in one column?

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439653 helps.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that normal text starts with `\vskip\topskip` while `\twocolumn[...]` and `\@topnewpage[...]` do not.  Whether this is deliberate or an oversight remains to be seen.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}% demonstrate the problem
\twocolumn[\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}]
\onecolumn
\chapter*{\contentsname}
\def\contentsname{\raisebox{-\topskip}{Contents}}% this will fix it
\twocolumn
\chapter*{\contentsname}
\onecolumn
\end{document}
```